# UpdatePanel not updating with large amounts of data

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have an UpdatePanel which contains GridView and submit button, selecting the submit button causes the update panel to update OK when the GridView contains not many records, however, when the grid view contians a large amount of data, clicking the submit button does not cause the UpdatePanel to update.

Any ideas, I do not know if there is a restriction on the amount of data that can be sent using the ScriptManage/UpdatePanel, but in one instance the page size is 718Kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any restrictions in size but maybe the page is just timing out somewhere?  The best idea if you can is to limit the amount of data that you are passing back and forth.

ek_ny's suggestion Re: EnableViewState is a good one that will slash your page sizes if you can implement it.

Another idea is to implement paging in your Gridview so that you are only displaying a manageable number of rows at a time.

Comment: ViewState might come in handy if you intend on having some controls that cause post-backs that do not result in rebind of the grid.  So plan well before disabling ViewState.  But I completely agree on implementing server side paging, it's almost always the ticket to responsive web pages.

Comment: Implemented paging on the GridView and this works a treat, I needed to maintain viewstate as the gridview is being monitored for changes on each row.

Answer (score 1):

If you rebind the GridView then you don't need the GridView to be in the ViewState and you can set the EnableViewState of the GridView property to false.